# UCanAccess data exception: numeric value out of range

Tags: java, database, exception, ucanaccess

I have a table called [Elenco_Aziende] from which I extract all the record in a resultset. [Elenco_Aziende] is in a relation one to many with other two tables called [Elenco_Autisti] and [Elenco_Veicoli] via a field called [Partita_IVA_Azienda] that is also primary key in [Elenco_Aziende] table.

After extracting all records from [Elenco_Aziende] I perform a loop for each value of [Partita_IVA_Azienda] and then open a new result set to try to read values in related fields of [Elenco_Autisti] and [Elenco_Veicoli] tables and do for each of them some operation.

And here comes strange thing: As long as [Partita_IVA_Azienda] (which is defined as a `Text` field in the Access DB) values are all the same length everything is OK when I try to read in [Elenco_Autisti] and [Elenco_Veicoli] tables, but if some of [Partita_IVA_Azienda] has a different length then I got error:

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.1 data exception: numeric value out of range

More precisely here is the nested loop scenario:

```
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"
        + filepath);



String qry = "SELECT * FROM Elenco_Aziende";

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry);
String cognometest = "";
String nometest ="";

while (rs.next()) {




    String partitaiva = "Partita IVA: "
            + rs.getString("Partita_IVA_Azienda") + "\n\r";


    String partitaivazienda = rs.getString("Partita_IVA_Azienda");

    Statement stmtautisti = con.createStatement();


    System.out.println("Sto per eseguire la query per partita iva azienda = " + partitaivazienda + "\n\r");


    String qryautisti = "SELECT * FROM Elenco_Autisti WHERE Partita_IVA_Azienda="
            + partitaivazienda; /*!!!!! AND HERE WHEN I EXECUTE NEXT QUERY IS WHERE I GET THE EXCEPTION net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.1 data exception: numeric value out of range more!!!!!*/
    ResultSet rsautisti = stmtautisti.executeQuery(qryautisti);



    while (rsautisti.next()) {

    do something here

    }


    Statement stmtveicoli = con.createStatement();
    String qryveicoli = "SELECT * FROM Elenco_Veicoli WHERE Partita_IVA_Azienda="
            + rs.getString("Partita_IVA_Azienda");
    ResultSet rsveicoli = stmtveicoli.executeQuery(qryveicoli);



    while (rsveicoli.next()) {

    do something else here

    }
```

that is as soon as I execute the query

```
String qryautisti = "SELECT * FROM Elenco_Autisti WHERE Partita_IVA_Azienda="+ partitaivazienda;
```

for a different length value of [Partita_IVA_Azienda] I get the problem.

I even tried to export the database in a comma separated value and reimporting it in a brand new one but it did not help. Furthermore, the problem seems to happen just for large number of records in tables [Elenco_Autisti] (138 records) and [Elenco_Veicoli] (287 records), while seems not to happen for small number of records. [Elenco_Aziende] is small (no more than 10 records).

Comment: is it possible for you to show all value of `partitaivazienda`? I assume that you may a really huge number here.

Comment: Is a message like "numeric value out of range" really to be expected for a *text field*? Don't you have to use quotes for a string in a SELECT statement?

Comment: If only you used prepared statements...

Answer (score 0):

According to the little of what I know about SQL, a WHERE with a text field should be written with the value in apostrophes:

```
String qryautisti = "SELECT * FROM Elenco_Autisti WHERE Partita_IVA_Azienda='"
                    + partitaivazienda + "'";
```

Comment: @Alf It would still be better to use a `PreparedStatement` and a *parameterized query*.